# Cannot pass variable in Powershell from function to script

Tags: powershell

Here is the code section I am having trouble with:

```
function getGroup {
$Script:confirmdggroup = "N"
$Script:dggroup = "none"
$dggroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the group to add a member'
write-host "You entered $dggroup"
$confirmdggroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'If the group name is correct enter Y'
write-host "You entered $confirmdggroup when asked to confirm group name"
}
```

If ($confirmdggroup -ne "Y") {getGroup}
write-host "Group name to be modified is $dggroup"
write-host "the confirmdggroup variable is: $confirmdggroup"

And here is an image of the input and output when I run it. You can see that the variables are properly assigned inside the function but not outside. What am I doing wrong?

[image: input and output]

ok I am trying to rewrite and not use "Script:" but I cannot get the function to return anything. Here is the new function:

```
function getGroup {
while($confirmDGGroup -ne "Y")
  {
    $DGGroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the Exchange group to modify'
    ""
    write-host "You entered $DGGroup"
    ""
    $confirmDGGroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'If the group name is correct enter Y'
  }
}
```

cls
write-host "This script will add or remove email addresses from an Exchange Distibution Group"
""
$GroupName = getGroup
write-host "The get group function returned $GroupName"
pause

And here is the output I get now:

```
This script will add or remove email addresses from an Exchange Distibution Group

Enter the name of the Exchange group to modify: office
You entered office
If the group name is correct enter Y: Y
The get group function returned  
Press Enter to continue...:
```

Comment: while you found your answer - leaving off the required `$Script:` scope - why on earth are you using manual scoping? [*frown*] it utterly destroys one of the safety factors of a function - semi-sandboxing your code. a function should have ONE want in [parameters] and ONE way out [returned object]. while there **_are_** situations that require it, i see no reason at all for your dangerous use of manual scoping.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but to be honest I rarely do any coding, only when I have a specific need or want to make tasks I do frequently easier. I was able to accomplish my task with the script I put together, in this case updating exchange groups without having to go to the website. I would have to research "manual scoping" to even understand a better way to do what I needed.

Comment: `manual scoping` is what `$Script:` as a variable prefix does. [*grin*] take a look at how functions are done in the script snippets you get with the ISE. all info should enter your function via parameters and should exit your function via an output. so that `$Test = Get-KoolStuff -StuffToWorkOn $ListOfThings` takes in the content of `$ListOfThings` and then outputs that to whatever is on the left of the `=` assignment operator. ///// if you have ever read of "spaghetti code" then you are aware of the problem with things that don't move from point to point _cleanly_. [*grin*]

Comment: So if I understand correctly I could move the variable used to confirm the correct name was entered to before the function name like so?

Comment: function getGroup {
$Script:DGGroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the Exchange group to modify'
write-host "You entered $DGGroup"
}<br/> $confirmDGGroup = getGroup

Comment: please, read up on functions - especially advanced functions. you are STILL using `$Script:` scope control and that is the entire point of this conversation. `one way in & one way out` - never use manually set scope unless you absolutely must.

Comment: I've been doing some more reading and tried rewriting the function so it does not use "Script:" as suggested but I cannot get it to return the value I entered. I couldn't figure out how to format the comment to add the updated code so I edited the original post and added it to the bottom.

Comment: please take a look at my modified answer. it seems to do what you want done and doesn't use any manual scope modifiers. [*grin*]

Comment: Lee,Thank you very much for providing the corrected script. This will be very helpful as I continue learning

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to  have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a function that gets user input, asks if it is correct, repeats if NOT correct, and finally sends the text out to the caller.

```
function Get-ExchangeGroupName
    {
    $Prompt = 'Please enter the Group name '

    $Choice = ''
    while ($Choice -eq '')
        {
        $Choice = Read-Host $Prompt
        Write-Host ('You entered [ {0} ].' -f $Choice)
        $YesNo = Read-Host '    Is that correct? [n/y]'
        if ($YesNo -eq 'y')
            {
            # send the result out to the caller
            $Choice
            }
            else
            {
            $Choice = ''
            }
        }
    } # function Get-ExchangeGroupName

$ChosenGroupName = Get-ExchangeGroupName
''
$ChosenGroupName
```

output with `n` & `y` responses to "is that correct?" ...

```
Please enter the Group name : qwerty
You entered [ qwerty ].
    Is that correct? [n/y]: n
Please enter the Group name : AlfaBravo
You entered [ AlfaBravo ].
    Is that correct? [n/y]: y

AlfaBravo
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I forgot to add the $Script: in front of the lines where the function was asking for input. Here is the corrected code:

```
function getGroup {
$Script:dggroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the group to add a member'
write-host "You entered $dggroup"
$Script:confirmdggroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'If the group name is correct enter Y'
write-host "You entered $confirmdggroup when asked to confirm group name"
}
```

If ($confirmdggroup -ne "Y") {getGroup}
write-host "Group name to be modified is $dggroup"
write-host "the confirmdggroup variable is: $confirmdggroup"